# How to send message direct (twitter) on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I had a nodejs server that I answered to a new direct messages. But Twitter changed the api and now It doesn’t work. I used the twit sdk for nodejs. So, I have investigating and I have got read new messages with the sdk “twitter-webhook” but I haven’t seen information about send a direct message or publish a tweet. 
Could you tell me some advice about how I should do it with this SDK? Or do I have to use other library to answer direct messages?
Thank you

Edit:  I have added the code but it is the sample with arguments where I have seen the received message

```
'use strict';
var debug = require('debug');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const twitterWebhooks = require('twitter-webhooks');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);


const userActivityWebhook = twitterWebhooks.userActivity({
    serverUrl: '',
    route: '/twitter', //default : '/'
    consumerKey: '',
    consumerSecret: '',
    accessToken: '',
    accessTokenSecret: '',
    environment: '',
    app
});



// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});

//Register your webhook url - just needed once per URL
userActivityWebhook.register();
userActivityWebhook.unsubscribe({
    userId: '',
    accessToken: '',
    accessTokenSecret: ''
}).then((c) => {
    //Subscribe for a particular user activity
    userActivityWebhook.subscribe({
        userId: '',
        accessToken: '',
        accessTokenSecret: ''
    })
        .then(function (userActivity) {
            userActivity
                .on('tweet_create', (data) => console.log(userActivity.id + ' - tweet_create'))
                .on('direct_message', (data) => {


                    console.log(userActivity.id + ' - direct_message');
                })
        })
        .catch((er) => {

            console.error(er);
        });
}).catch((er) => {
    userActivityWebhook.subscribe({
        userId: '',
        accessToken: '',
        accessTokenSecret: ''
    })
        .then(function (userActivity) {
            console.log("asasas");
            userActivity
                .on('tweet_create', (data) => console.log(userActivity.id + ' - tweet_create'))
                .on('direct_message', (data) => {
                    console.log(userActivity.id + ' - direct_message');
                })
        })
        .catch((er) => {

            console.error(er);
        });

    });

//listen to any user activity
userActivityWebhook.on('event', (event, userId, data) => {

    if (event == "direct_message") {
        console.log("userid: " + userId);
        console.log("senderid: " + data["message_create"]["sender_id"]);
        console.log("userid: " + data["message_create"]["message_data"].text);


        console.log(userId + ' - event - ' + event);
    }

});

//listen to unknown payload (in case of api new features)
userActivityWebhook.on('unknown-event', (rawData) => console.log(rawData));
```

Comment: Hello! Please could you add some code to your question? It would be very helpful to us to see what you have written so we can see which bit is not working. Thanks :-)

Comment: I have attached the code, it is very near to the sample. But my question is about how I can use the sdk to answer the user, in this case, on the function where It detect the new message. Thank you

Comment: Thanks. Have you taken a look at the documentation for sending DMs? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/direct-messages/sending-and-receiving/api-reference/new-event

Comment: Yes, I have seen it but avoid build auth header, I'm using SDK but then, by your comment, the sdk that I'm using doesn't Support to send DM, is correct?

Comment: Could you link to the SDK you are using?